# How to resize the scrollbar from a QTextEdit in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using a QTextEdit widget in my python GUI - designed with PyQt4. The vertical scrollbar appears as soon as the text doesn't fit anymore in the QTextEdit widget. But the scrollbar itself is so small (high dpi screen). How can I enlarge the scrollbar, such that clicking and dragging it gets more user friendly?

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried a stylesheet?  I think you might be able to use something like `QScrollBar::handle  { min-width: 16px }` though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Try using the "fusion" widget style: apparently it scales better.

Comment: Thank you @strubbly and ekhumoro . I have tried both your suggestions - but without success. But thanks though for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using:

```py
QScrollBar::handle:vertical { min-height : 16px; }
```

I was trying to display over 40000 lines in a `QTextEdit` and the scroll bar kept getting too small to even see. I struggled to get this working for hours, but this was the solution for me. I hope this helps.