# How to install new QStyle for PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm writing a GUI in `PyQt4` (and migrating to `PyQt5`). This is how I start my GUI:

```
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion')) # <- Choose the style
    myGUI = MyMainWindow("First GUI")
    app.exec_()
```

**Default Styles in PyQt4 :**

Apparently, `PyQt4` has the following styles:

- `'Windows'`
- `'WindowsXP'`
- `'WindowsVista'`
- `'Motif'`
- `'CDE'`
- `'Plastique'`
- `'Cleanlooks'`

**Default Styles in PyQt5 :**

`PyQt5` has the following styles:

- `'Windows'`
- `'WindowsXP'`
- `'WindowsVista'`
- `'Fusion'`

**Custom styles?**

None of these styles has proper support for HiDpi displays (4k and the like). For example, scrollbars are too small( see this post: [How to resize the scrollbar from a QTextEdit in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149631/how-to-resize-the-scrollbar-from-a-qtextedit-in-pyqt)). And I didn't even mention the problems for those people with unsharp eyesight..

Do you know a style (preferably open-source) that provides good support for 4k displays or for people with eyesight problems?

If so, how can one download this style, and install it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you seen Qt's [High DPI documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)?

Comment: Thank you @TheCompiler . How do I practically implement this in python?

Comment: I don't have a HighDPI screen myself, but something like `app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)` (assuming `app` is your `QApplication` instance) might already help.

Comment: Maybe out of topic: With Fusion style the default display for QGroupBox is wrong. Use WindowsVista style instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer (or let's say a workaround) through another question:
[How to make Icon in QMenu larger (PyQt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396707/how-to-make-icon-in-qmenu-larger-pyqt)

The most straightforward way to create a new `QStyle` is deriving it from an existing one. PyQt provides the `QProxyStyle` class for that purpose. Below is the example that I've also given in the [How to make Icon in QMenu larger (PyQt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396707/how-to-make-icon-in-qmenu-larger-pyqt) question. In this example, a custom `QStyle` is created (derived from "Fusion" style), and the custom style provides very big icons for the `QMenu`.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

# Create a custom "QProxyStyle" to enlarge the QMenu icons
#-----------------------------------------------------------
class MyProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    pass
    def pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option=None, widget=None):

        if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize:
            return 40
        else:
            return QProxyStyle.pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option, widget)


# This is the main window class (with a simple QMenu implemented)
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()

        # 1. Set basic geometry and color.
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello World')
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(200, 200, 200))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        # 2. Create the central frame.
        self.centralFrame = QFrame()
        self.centralFrame.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralFrame)

        # 3. Create a menu bar.
        myMenuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = myMenuBar.addMenu("&File")

        testMenuItem = QAction(QIcon("C:\\my\\path\\myFig.png"), "&Test", self)
        testMenuItem.setStatusTip("Test for icon size")
        testMenuItem.triggered.connect(lambda: print("Menu item has been clicked!"))

        fileMenu.addAction(testMenuItem)

        # 4. Show the window.
        self.show()

# Start your Qt application based on the new style
#---------------------------------------------------
if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myStyle = MyProxyStyle('Fusion')    # The proxy style should be based on an existing style,
                                        # like 'Windows', 'Motif', 'Plastique', 'Fusion', ...
    app.setStyle(myStyle)

    myGUI = TestWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Just copy-paste the code snippet, and paste it in a *.py file. Of course, you should replace the path to the icon with a valid path on your local computer. Just provide a complete path ("C:..") to be 100% sure that Qt finds the icon drawing.

Try it out, and you should get the following window:

[image]